# Android Spanned Text while deleting smiles shows text

Tags: android, android-edittext, spanned

I have `SpannedText` in `EditText` and I am replacing text with smiles for example *cool* replaced with smile. But when I am pressing Backspace on android phone **(Nexus 5 kitkat 4.4.4)** it shows "(Smile)cool" then it deletes the letters at last the smile itself. But on **Genymotion** emulator it works as needed. What is wrong with my code?

This code is in for

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
                Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
                int spanSmileHeight = (displayHeight>displayWidth) ? ((int) ((double) displayHeight/25)) : ((int) ((double) displayWidth/25));
                int spanSmileWidth = ((int) ((double) spanSmileHeight/b.getHeight())*b.getWidth())+15;
                Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, spanSmileWidth, spanSmileHeight, false);
                Drawable sd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapResized);
                sd.setBounds(0, 0, spanSmileWidth, spanSmileHeight);
                addPattern(emoticons, smileyCode, sd);
...

ImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        int start = Math.max(message.getSelectionStart(), 0);
                        int end = Math.max(message.getSelectionEnd(), 0);
                        message.getText().replace(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end),
                                smileyCode, 0, smileyCode.length());
                        message.setText(getSmiledText(view.getContext(), message.getText()));
                        message.setSelection(start + smileyCode.length());
```

and this

```
public static boolean addSmiles(Context context, Spannable spannable) {
        boolean hasChanges = false;
        for (Map.Entry<Pattern, Drawable> entry : emoticons.entrySet()) {
            Matcher matcher = entry.getKey().matcher(spannable);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                boolean set = true;
                for (ImageSpan span : spannable.getSpans(matcher.start(),
                        matcher.end(), ImageSpan.class))
                    if (spannable.getSpanStart(span) >= matcher.start()
                            && spannable.getSpanEnd(span) <= matcher.end())
                        spannable.removeSpan(span);
                    else {
                        set = false;
                        break;
                    }
                if (set) {
                    hasChanges = true;
                    spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(entry.getValue(), ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM),
                            matcher.start(), matcher.end(),
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        }
        return hasChanges;
    }

    public static Spannable getSmiledText(Context context, CharSequence text) {
        Spannable spannable = spannableFactory.newSpannable(text);
        addSmiles(context, spannable);
        return spannable;
    }
```

Before bacspace

[image: before backspace]

After backspace(of virtual keyobard) pressed

[image: after backspace]

The log output:

```
09-01 06:22:21.280    1271-1271/com.nnadir.wapchat.app I/wapChat﹕ *sad**sad**sad**sad**sad**cat**cat*
09-01 06:23:32.060    1271-1271/com.nnadir.wapchat.app I/wapChat﹕ *sad**sad**sad**sad**sad**cat**cat
09-01 06:23:32.080    1271-1271/com.nnadir.wapchat.app I/wapChat﹕ *sad**sad**sad**sad**sad**cat**
09-01 06:23:32.084    1271-1271/com.nnadir.wapchat.app I/wapChat﹕ *sad**sad**sad**sad**sad**cat**cat
```

3 more times

```
09-01 06:24:07.980    1271-1271/com.nnadir.wapchat.app I/wapChat﹕ *sad**sad**sad**sad**sad**cat**ca
09-01 06:24:08.264    1271-1271/com.nnadir.wapchat.app I/wapChat﹕ *sad**sad**sad**sad**sad**cat**c
09-01 06:24:08.668    1271-1271/com.nnadir.wapchat.app I/wapChat﹕ *sad**sad**sad**sad**sad**cat**
```

And here smile deleted

```
09-01 06:24:09.248    1271-1271/com.nnadir.wapchat.app I/wapChat﹕ *sad**sad**sad**sad**sad**cat*
```

Comment: your code? what code?

Comment: I have added code to the question.

Comment: I have found that it happens on Nexus 5

Comment: try to use one character long span

Comment: Then if I want to add 100 smiles, how to be? and that names of smiles taken from the names of files.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251226/remove-whole-spannable-with-backspace a comment suggests subclassing EditText and handle backspace, if icon, and bypass to super if normal text

Comment: when using setSpan make sure that start == end  - 1, this will make your ImageSpan one character long span

Comment: when start==end-1 not all text replaced with smile but only first character.

But here (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42904#c8) I've found that if I change targetSDK to 15 then KEYCODE_DEL is captured and I tried it and it worked. may be this is walktrouhg.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way how to prevent this. If we change targetSDK to 15 then smiles are deleted succesfully.