# How to ask android to get a string from a specified file?

Tags: android

I have string.xml into files values-ar , values-fr and I want to get a string value from one of them manually.
for example:

```
R.string-ar....
R.string-fr....
```

I know that the system search the string according to the system language or the app language.
but I want to get a string from a specified file regardless of the system or the app language!

Comment: i think you have to set the locale to FR or AR then get the string, otherwise, i think you have to parse the XML values-xx file yourself.

Comment: no I don't want to switch local inside my app !

Comment: it might be ineffective. changing local does not effect the view (activity)\ unless its reloaded or app restarted, so you can set locale get value, roll back to 1st locale and keep on

Comment: It's kind of a hack, but I'd do the very same way - no other way comes to my mind.

Comment: @Yazan could you write some code !

Comment: i have added an answer

Comment: @david you can try `ResourceBundle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

Locale newlocale = new Locale("fr");
setLocale(newlocale );
String value = getResources().getString(R.string.username);//fr string
setLocale(current );


public void setLocale(Locale locale){
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: edit was made, Locale.setDefault(locale); first line of the function was newlocale (wrong)

Comment: Yazan can you take a look at my question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566116/android-spanned-text-while-deleting-smiles-shows-text

Answer (score 0):

This is changing locale programmatically, but you need to call this in every activity onCreate

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
// Change locale settings in the app.
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```